# Multiple condition inside a DQL query

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I need to build a SQL/DQL query for my dating website, which retrieve all users with some matched fields like sex, age, location and 3 interests. I don't know how to create multiple condition inside my DQL Query. I've started with something like that:

`SELECT u FROM MyUserBundle:User u WHERE u.sex LIKE :preference");
                             $query->setParameters(array('preference' => '%' . $preference . '%'
                             'age' => '%' . $age . '%'
                             'location' => '%' . $location . '%'
                              'interest' => '%' . $interests . '%'));
$users = $query->getResult();`

I'm using Symfony2 and Doctrine2 and it doesn't work for me. Someone can show me how to manage multiple condition inside my query ? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of more sophisticated queries, better use Doctrine2 [Query Builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html)

```
$qb =  $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$qb
   ->select('u')
   ->from('MyUserBundle:User', 'u')
   ->where($qb->expr()->like('u.sex', ':preferense'))
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('u.age', ':age'))
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('u.location', ':location'))
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('u.interest', ':interest'))
   ->setParameters(array(
      'preferense' => '%'.$preference.'%',
      'age' => '%'.$location.'%',
      'location' => '%'.$location.'%',
      'interest' => '%'.$interests.'%',
   ));

$users = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Tip: if $interests is array use foreach.